# Execute C# Code from string by CodeDom "Performance"?

Tags: c#, codedom

I have an application perform some calculation logic and this app work with many customers

I want to change some formulas for some customers so,I found an article talking on how to execute C# code from strings [here](http://simeonpilgrim.com/blog/2007/12/04/compiling-and-running-code-at-runtime/) by CodeDom and it's working for my case and will solve many problems,

but I don't know about the performance of this way will be bad or not?

Comment: How can we possibly know? Measure it with a profiler.

Comment: I mean the strategy itself if i have formula x= a+b;
if i store this formula in db and execute it dynamically there a time for compiling the Assembly is this time will be a problem or it's very fast?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends.

The first execution will be quite slow. .NET has to run the native `csc.exe` to compile the code. However, after the compilation step, you're left with a method like any other.

So, if you care about GUI response speed - it's not *that* slow. If you care about applying the same formula to a lot of data, it has very little impact as well. Caching the compiled method is the key.

Comment: does this mean that in second time i call the same code there is no compiling time , it gets from cashed ?

Comment: @user897645 No, you have to do the caching yourself. You need to take the result of the compilation, and e.g. create a delegate on that method.

Comment: I can do the following
1 - Create a screen to setup formulas
2 - Compile an Assembly after saving the formula
3 - Load this assembly and call myFormula when i need in calculation logic

by this way i will cash the compiler work